# How can I mock multiple prints?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, assert

I have this function:

```
def function1():
    number1 = int(input())
    number2 = int(input())
    print("Calculate sum")
    sum = number1 + number2
    print("Calculate product")
    product = number1 * number2
    print("Calculate substraction")
    sub = number1 - number2
    print("Done")
```

I have to do an unit test for this function but I don't know how to check all the prints. I implemented this function that can verify the last print but I want to verify with assert and mock all the printed messages.

```
@patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=StringIO)
def test_main(mock_stdout):
    input_main = [6, 2]
    with patch('builtins.input', side_effect=input_main):
        main()
        assert mock_stdout.getvalue() == 'Done\n'

test_main()
```

Comment: `mock_stdout` should contain *all* the strings written by `print`, not just the last one.

Comment: I ran your code, testing `function1` instead of `main` and `mock_stdout` had the expected `'Calculate sum\nCalculate product\nCalculate substraction\nDone\n'`. Are you testing something else? Is this not the complete code?

Comment: @MikeRoll how can I print the content of mock_stdout?

Comment: I just went over that with a debugger. But if you really want to print, you should patch `sys.stdout` inside the function `with patch('sys.stdout', ...) as mock_stdout:` and print after exiting that with block, as the original stdout will be restored.

Answer (score 2):

Using unittest you can do:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, call

@patch('builtins.print')
def test_your_function(self, mock_print):
   your_function()
   self.assertEqual(mock_print.mock_calls, [call("Calculate sum"), 
                                            call("Calculate product"),
                                            call("Calculate substraction"),
                                            call("Done")])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: instead of self.assertEqual() it's neater to use mock_print.assert_has_calls([call("Calculate sum"), ...])

Comment: to answer my own comment above, self.assertEqual(Mock.mock_calls) is better because Mock.assert_has_calls() does not catch *additional* calls that aren't in the list

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [native pytest capability instead](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/capture.html#accessing-captured-output-from-a-test-function):

```
def test_myoutput(capsys):  # or use "capfd" for fd-level
    print("hello")
    sys.stderr.write("world\n")
    captured = capsys.readouterr()
    assert captured.out == "hello\n"
    assert captured.err == "world\n"
    print("next")
    captured = capsys.readouterr()
    assert captured.out == "next\n"
```